# Data in Parent class

Tags: java, class, parent, member

I have two classes `A` and `B`. in class `A` i create an object of `B`.
From within the object x, I would like to access values of datamembers `one` and `two`.
Is the only solution for that, passing it as parameter like

```
b=new B(one,two)
```

?. I donot want to extend, because class `A` is a frame and class `B` is a panel.

```
class A
{
    private int one;
    private String two;
    private myMethod()
    {
        B x=new B();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can pass an instance of class `A` to instance of `B` via constructor.

Comment: accessors and new b(this) if you need fresh data every in b. As you described for static data

Comment: I have multiple little classes like c,d,e,f,g
Wont it be bad to pass full parent A everytime by value?

Comment: @XperiazX, No it wont be. What you are passing is a reference of a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can go (I'll discuss each below)

1. Pass the parameters one by one
2. Pass the whole frame
3. **Extract an interface and pass that**

---

Ad 1. This is the easiest approach, simply use a constructor like

```
public B(int one, String two) {
    ...
}
```

As you already mentioned, this is cumbersome if the number of parameters is large.

---

Ad 2. This is not a good idea. Does the panel really need to have access to all the properties of the frame? No, it doesn't. For instance you could:

```
public B(MyFrame a) {
    ...
    a.setVisible(false);
}
```

which is absolutely undesired. Besides, the problem with circular references is that you cannot make changes in isolation: changes to your frame can cause changes in the panel and vise versa.

---

Ad 3. This would be my preferred approach. You create an interface that provides *exactly the functionality you need*:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public int getOne();
    public String getTwo();
}
```

Then you let your class `A` implement that interface:

```
public class A implements MyInterface {
    ...

    public int getOne() {
        return one;
    }

    public String getTwo() {
        return two;
    }
}
```

You know change the constructor of `B` to

```
public B(MyInterface a) {
    // use a.getOne() and a.getTwo() to get your data
}
```

And you can still create `B` from `A` as

```
B b = new B(this);
```

The three main advantages are:

1. You need to pass only one parameter that contains all required data
2. You don't expose more of class `A` than needed
3. Class `B` does not explicitly depend on class `A` (only on interface `MyInterface`)

Answer (score 1):

```
class B
{
    private int one;
    private String two;
    public B(int one,String two) //constructor of B
    {
       this.one=one;
       this.two=two; 
    }

  // getter setters
}
```

If you create class B as above you can call `B b=new B(one, two);`

Comment: Yes this is the method I used. However I have to pass around 5 values of different type, making constructor header rather large.

Answer (score 1):

If you want one and two to be accessible outside of the class you can -

1. Make them public
2. Wrap them with a public property (a public get and a private set)

Then you can pass an instance of a (for example by using the this keyword) to the constructor of b;

Answer (score 1):

If classes A and B are separate components than I am afraid you don't have another choice.

If on the other hand class B belongs to class A in a functionality-wise manner you could make class B an inner class of A:

```
public class A {

    int one;

    class B {

        private void doSomething() {
            one = one + 1;   // inside B you can access memebers of A
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: panel class B belongs to the Frame A.
Is that relation enough? (containment relation)

Comment: @XperiazX It is not enough. There may be another class C that also has a class B as a member. The question you should answer is this: Is the class B going to be used independently of class A? Does it make sense to use it anywhere that class A not exists? If yes, then it is an independent class. If no, then this class belongs to class A and you can go ahead and make it an inner class. At least generally speaking. If you provide a more concrete example, I would be able to provide a more specific answer

Answer (score 0):

You can delcare like this

```
    class B
   {
        private int one;
        private String two;

     // getter setters methods
   }
```

and call form `Class A 's myMethod()` should like thid

```
private myMethod()
{
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    b.setOne(A.one);
    b.setTwo(A.two);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be as follows:

```
class B
{
   A a;
   public B(A a){
   this.a = a;
}
}
```

This will require that you have public accessor methods for the attributes of class `A`

Comment: This is a bad pattern. `A` explicitly depends on `B` and `B` explicitly depends on `A`. This kind of circular references are never necessary. For instance, pass only the relevant parts of `A` to `B`.

Comment: @Heuster . So the essential parts can be passed only as parameters?

Comment: Well, in that case every addition of any parameter in `A` which is needed by `B` will call for change of constructor or overloaded constructor.